# Get result from activity in service(android)

Tags: android

I am writing service in android, I have a problem, I want to start activity in service and get result from activity, how can I do? 
Best Regards

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: my project want to communication with hardware, this communication is in activity. In fact i have service that get message from another application for communicate with hardware, when service gets message, it must start activity and get result from activity.

Best Regards

Comment: I want to use startActivityForResultin service.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what type of service are you using but;

If you are using IntentService, the best way to do it with BroadcastReciever Class.

http://www.mobiledevguide.com/2013/01/how-to-use-intentservice-in-android.html

This tutorial will help you on that topic.

Comment: my project want to communication with hardware, this communication is in activity. In fact i have service that get message from another application for communicate with hardware, when service gets message, it must start activity and get result from activity.

Best Regards